# Espresso tests failing after unrelated changes

Tags: android, android-studio, junit, android-espresso

I had my espresso tests running. And unfortunately after some random changes all of my tests are failing. And I have never seen this error message at all:

Error message:-

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No interface method trackUsage(Ljava/lang/String;)V in class Landroid/support/test/internal/runner/tracker/UsageTracker; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.support.test.internal.runner.tracker.UsageTracker' appears in /data/app/mu.organyze.test-1/base.apk)
```

Here's my dependency:-

```
dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        })

        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
        compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

        testCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.1'
        testCompile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker:1.2'
        testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.12.0'
        testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-android:2.12.0'


        androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0'
        androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
        androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.1'
        androidTestCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.12.0'
        androidTestCompile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker:1.2'
        androidTestCompile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:1.2'


        androidTestUtil 'com.android.support.test:orchestrator:1.0.1'
        androidTestCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-integration:1.3'
    }
```

Comment: This may help you [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39841341/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-no-interface-method-ontransitiontoidlev)

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to dependencies:-

> com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.0